# get Child View of a Group in Expandable List View

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am trying to get Child View object from a expandable list view, but i could n't find any methods for it. I could get the group view by using `getChildAt(int index)` but i am looking for a method which returns child view by getting group position and child position. Is there any method for it, Please help.

Comment: when you get group , you can get it's child too, getChildAt(0).getChildAt(2);

Comment: I tried it already, it doesn't work.

Comment: getChildAt return only visible view.index start with zero. can you tell your target,maybe better way exist

Comment: did you find any solution ?